# Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

Looking to put a table and a figure side by side so that the table and figure have their own captions. A crude sketch

```
 ------------              -----------------
    TABLE 
  | a |  b |                     FIGURE
  | c |  d |
 ------------             
Table 2: Caption           -----------------
                           Figure 7: Caption
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```
\begin{table}%
\centering
\parbox{0.4\textwidth}{
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{tabular}{| l | r |} \hline
some & table\\
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\caption{Table}
\label{tab:table}
}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.53\textwidth}%
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{awesome}
\caption{Figure}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

But that gives two `Table X: Caption` captions. I didn't find anything in `subfig`.

Help?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101980/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-table-caption-above-figure-caption-below

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use a `floatrow` environment of the [package](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) of the same name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. Worked perfectly: floated, correct labelling, separate captions, and even  handled the footnote in my table correctly!

Comment: I don't know where I had my head. I could have hit on this idea, too. (+1)

Comment: I am getting crazy with this minifigure. I can put two figures side by side, but I cannot get two captions (one left, one right). And I copied examples from the internet!
Your examples work, but how to put a figure with \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figs2/fig5.eps}
in your examples and not a black square and a table?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: @alex: In my example, replace `\rule{3cm}{3cm}` with `\includegraphics{<whatever>}`.

Comment: :) ...23 hours to go.

Comment: It was a joke, I swear! It was a joke! And I didn't remember I answered one of *your* questions! ... But this is a nice surprise. :-)

Comment: ...are you saying my questions aren't memorable? :P Anyways, don't spend it all in one shop.

Comment: I get the error: Package floatrow Error: Do not use float package with floatrow. will floatrow replace float? or is there another workaround ?

Comment: @Fry `floatrow` replaces `float`.

Comment: @lockstep. Where should the `figure.eps` be loaded in the upper code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidC. Instead of `\rule`.

Comment: The suggestion and the code example are great, however, the figure and table seem to each take half the page width. What can one do, if the figure is rather thin, but the table rather wide? Here is a screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29095240/2014-10-06%20Selection_003.png

Comment: @PeterLustig I ended up using the second option of [Thorsten's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6854/38080)... a pity it doesn't float, although synchronizing two different floats numbers is a bit difficult.

Comment: i get: Undefined control sequence. \newfloatcommand

Answer (score 83):

You can use the »[caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)« package. See code below for an example derived from the package manual.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2  \&  \tablename~\thetable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \qquad
    \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\hline
      Table head & Table head \\ \hline
      Some values & Some values \\
      Some values & Some values \\
      Some values & Some values \\
      Some values & Some values \\
      Some values & Some values \\
      Some values & Some values \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionlistentry[table]{A table beside a figure}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
    \caption{A table beside a figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You will find more details in the manual. This is not exactly what you want, but it would float.

---

[image]

---

**Supplement:**

Another solution that would give the desired output. But this won't float.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    \captionof{figure}{A table beside a figure}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
      Table head & Table head \\ \hline
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \captionof{table}{A table beside a figure}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thorsten, many thanks for the detailed answer and excellent examples. I went with the other answer since it's essentially a floating version of your second example where I can have separate captions.

Comment: why does this no longer work if you try to put the captions above the figure and table?

Comment: @emily a fix for that can be found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459423/table-next-to-figure-with-table-caption-on-top-but-figure-caption-on-bottom

Comment: with the minipage version, when table title is at the top, and the figure is taller, can you set the table verticle_alignment=centre? or align at top.