# Figure and table side-by-side in subfloats

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, subfloats

A very similar question has been asked before:

> [Table and Figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions)

I'm trying to accomplish this, but while using the `subfig` package. The image below depicts *almost* what I want, but as you can see, the table is not aligned correctly:

[image]

The TeX I'm working with is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{A figure and a table, side-by-side}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A figure left of a table]{
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    }
    \subfloat[A table right of a figure]{
        \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{figure}
```

I've tried throwing a few minipages into the mix, but to no avail. How can I align the top of the table to the top of the figure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table and Figure side-by-side with independent captions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions)

Comment: You should add the code you use, because the result is not the same with the default settings.

Comment: @egreg You're right; I tried a clean document and they align just fine. I'll try to figure out what's causing the problem and post it as the answer.

Comment: Gonzalo, the difference here is that I'm trying to use subfloats. References to the figure and the table would appear as 3.1(a) and 3.2(b). The other question I cited specifically calls for independent captions.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The caption package version you use is too old to work fine with the actual version of hyperref.

That's explaining both issues, the wired behaviour when used with the subfig package, and the error you get when using the subcaption package. So updating the caption package (or even better: your whole TeX system) should help.

(Current versions of the hyperref package need at least caption v3.1m from 2010/01/09)

Addendum: The very next version 1.1b of the subcaption package will typeout a more reasonable error message.

Comment: Thanks, this instantly resolved it! I opened up the MiKTeX Package Manager and updated a few packages, and it's working perfectly now.

Comment: I've noticed I do have to shuffle the imports around, as cmhughes mentioned. Some orderings reproduce the original problem, but I'm delighted that this problem is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem, the following worked for me:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{A figure and a table, side-by-side}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A figure left of a table]{
        \raisebox{-.5\height}{\rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}}
    }
    \subfloat[A table right of a figure]{
        \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

My specific problem appears to be caused by the `hyperref` package. Removing `\usepackage{hyperref}` resolved the layout problem, although I don't know exactly what was causing it.

With `subfig`, I get the following warning:

> \caption will not be redefined since it's already on input line 15

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

%% Enabling this package appears to cause the problem
% \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{A figure and a table, side-by-side}
    \centering
    \subfloat[A figure left of a table]{
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}  %% <- line 15
    }
    \subfloat[A table right of a figure]{
        \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With `subcaption`, I get the following compilation error:

> Package caption Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \caption on input line 30 in "test2.tex"

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}

%% Enabling this causes problems
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
    }
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{}{
        \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
            Table head & Table head \\ \hline
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\
            Some values & Some values \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Test images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}  %% <- line 30
```

Comment: Hmmm... adding `hyperref` to your code snippet (and loading `subfig`) doesn't allow me to reproduce the strange behaviour mentioned, so there must be something else going on. Can you complete your code to a proper minimal working example illustrating the problem?

Comment: Would another approach be useful for you? I mean, using the `subcaption` package instead of `subfig`?

Comment: That was really not obvious! An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) should be included at all times...

Comment: Nop. With the code you just posted I still can't reproduce the problem (after uncommenting the `hyperref` line).

Comment: I've added the code I'm working with. If it's relevant, I'm using MiKTeX 2.9. Gonzalo, I've tried `subcaption` as well, which causes compile errors. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm completely puzzled now. Could it be that either my `hyperref` package or my entire installation here is botched?

Comment: Can you add the line `\listfiles` before, `\begin{document}` and post the output/

Comment: I've pasted the file list here: http://pastebin.com/JgvWsiWs

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the unwanted output. I assume the actual document is a lot more complicated- be careful to load the `hyperref` package last- see this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Comment: Yes, that works! Including `hyperref` as the first include in the first example resolves it. For the `subcaption` example, however, I still get the error.