# PGFPLOTS: figure and table formatting

Tags: tables, pgfplots, graphs

Just after an hour spending browsing through the `pgfplots` manual, I am trying to have a figure and a table side by side (both the figure and the table use the same data). So I still have lot to learn!

So here is `apples.dat` file:

```
%Apples that went bad
year    value
2008    12053   %31 Dec 2007
2009    15792   %31 Dec 2008   
2010    22907   %31 Dec 2009  
2011    30997   %31 Dec 2010
```

And here are my plot commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,height=5cm,compat=newest}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xmin=2008,
xmax=2012,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
mark=x,line width=1pt,
axis y line = none,
nodes near coords,
color=black,
grid=major
]
xlabel=year,
ylabel=value]
\addplot+ file[skip first = true,x=year,y=value,const plot mark right]{apples.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={year,value}]{apples.dat}

\end{document}
```

I am saving space by eliminating the `y` values and tick marks.

Questions:

1. How to make the figure and the table appear side by side?
2. If I need to rotate the two floats (figure and table) together at the same time and turn them 90 deg anticlockwise so that the appear in the landscape mode, how to proceed?
3. I've tried using the `const plot mark right` option in `\addplot` but it doesn't work. Why?
4. Why does the `mark=x` option doesn't work in my code?
5. Why does the `color=black` option doesn't work in my code?
6. If I want to output everything as an eps file. How to proceed? I have tried using

   ```
   \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
   \tikzexternalize% activate externalization!
   ```

but this doesn't work with the conventional LaTeX > dvips > ps2pdf route. So how to get an eps?

I am using TeXLive 2011 (with everything updated last week) on Win XP.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: It may be better to divide this into several questions. For #1, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/figure-and-table-side-by-side-in-subfloats and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions

Comment: Thanks but for someone who knows pgfplots well, these should quite easy queries which will not take much space to answer. If I see that one or more queries is(are) giving problem(s) or need(s) a longer answer, then I will go for several posts. It depends on the feedback that I receive here.

Comment: Yes, but your first two questions isn't really related to pgfplots at all.

Comment: But for the table, we use a command like \pgfplotstabletypeset which is part of pgfplotstable. I thought an elegant solution existed within pgfplots itself that can make the figure and table appear together. I will leave the queries like this for now and wait for some responses. If I need to create a separate post, I shall do it then. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Put both the plot and the table inside the `figure` environment. You can get a figure and a table caption if you load the `caption` package and use the `\captionof{<type>}{<caption>}` command.
2. Enclose all the stuff in your `figure` environment in `\rotatebox{90}{<...>}`. You don't need to load additional packages if you're using TikZ.
3. `const plot mark right` needs to be supplied to `\addplot [<options>]`, not `\addplot table [<options>]`.
4. The same goes for `mark=x`. The correct syntax is `\addplot [mark=x] table...`.
5. `color=black` in the `axis` options works fine, but probably not as you expected. Try setting `color=red` in the axis options: The axis lines will be red. I assume you want all plots to be black (Hint: Don't say "Doesn't work", be specific!). For that, you need to add `every axis plot post/.style={draw=black}`, which will append the option to the `\addplot` options after everything else has been set, or specify `color=black` in the `\addplot [<options>]`.
6. No idea.

Bonus: For printing years, you would want to set `x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
     use comma,
     1000 sep={}}`. Same goes for `\pgfplotstabletypeset`: Here, you can add

```
columns/year/.style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={}
    }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{apples.dat}
%Apples that went bad
year    value
2008    12053   %31 Dec 2007
2009    15792   %31 Dec 2008   
2010    22907   %31 Dec 2009  
2011    30997   %31 Dec 2010
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,height=5cm,compat=newest}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
enlargelimits=false,
xmin=2008,
xmax=2012,
x tick label style={
    yshift=-0.5ex,
    rotate=45,
    anchor=east,    
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
     use comma,
     1000 sep={}
},
line width=1pt,
axis y line = none,
nodes near coords,
every axis plot post/.style={color=black},
grid=major,
xlabel=year,
ylabel=value]
\addplot [mark=x,const plot mark right] file[skip first = true,x=year,y=value]{apples.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{A pretty plot}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\centering
\captionof{table}{The data table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={year,value},
    columns/year/.style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={}
    }]{apples.dat}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using all latest versions of pgfplots and Tikz. And your code compiles fine also. Does `\addplot [const plot mark right] table ...` not suppose to draw horozontal lines with the points at the right of the interval? `\addplot [mark=x] table...` works now. And color = red is ok too. The way my code was written was not correct. 1 vote up.

Comment: With color = red, the graph line and the markers turn red. But the axes remain black.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Ah, now I understand what you meant. You have to be careful where you supply your options: Plot options like `mark=x` or `const plot mark right` don't belong in the `axis` options directly, or in the `table` options, but either in the `\addplot` options or in `every axis plot post/.style={...}`