# Table and Figure side-by-side with Table caption above, Figure caption below

Tags: positioning, subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

A continuation of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions).

I'm fighting a page-limit in a single-column layout and I need to put a Figure and a Table side-by-side and provide them with independent captions. However, the style guide for the publishers (LNCS) wants Figure captions below and Table captions above (probably something to do with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/why-should-a-table-caption-be-placed-above-the-table)).

=======================================================

If I adapt @lockstep's `floatrow` example from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions) accordingly to have a Table caption above ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content

%% **********************************
%% just adding \captop to original example
%% **********************************
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[\captop][\FBwidth]

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

=======================================================

The problem becomes clear ...

[image]

=======================================================

The `floatrow` doesn't correctly line up the Table and Caption. I reluctantly tried to use `vspace` to solve the problem, but it didn't work out.

Any suggestions on how to get these two to align? I'm happy to accept any alignment that ensures that the Table and Figure fit within the same "box".

(A similar-ish question was [asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/figure-and-table-side-by-side-in-subfloats), but specific for `subfig` and with a very localised problem it seems.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want them vertically centered, you can use `\CenterFloatBoxes`, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\CenterFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox
  {\includegraphics{image}}
  {\caption{A caption for a figure in a figure and a table side by side}\label{fig:test}}
\killfloatstyle
\ttabbox
  {\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline
    column1a & column2a \\
    column1b & column2b \\
    column1c & column2c \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  }
  {\caption{A caption for a table in a figure and a table side by side}\label{tab:test}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also `\TopFloatBoxes` for alignment at the top and `\BottomFloatBoxes`, for alignment at the bottom.

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: I probably should have spotted that. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an option similar to \CenterFloatBoxes, but where only the image/table size is used for centering and not the caption? For instance, if I have a large caption for one of the two objects, then it looks weird as the objects are not vertically centered at all. At least not based on their actual graphics.

Comment: Is there a simple way to have the table caption at the bottom?

Answer (score 9):

Another solution, using package `capt-of` and parboxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\parbox[t]{4cm}{\null
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
  \captionof{figure}{A figure}%
}
\parbox[t]{8cm}{\null
\centering
  \vskip-\abovecaptionskip
  \captionof{table}[t]{A table}%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hadn't encountered the `capt-of` package before. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: `floatrow` seems to conflict with the `figure` package, which is included in `subcaption` among other packages, but `capt-of` works fine in that situation.