# Inserting citation inside ERT code in LyX

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, captions

How do I cite a reference inside ERT code in LyX? Inside the ERT code I am unable to select Insert-->Citation as I usually do.

The reason I need to do this is further to an answer to a previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116722/30713 in which the caption text is now inside the ERT code and I need to include a citation inside the table caption.

Answer (score 3):

Within an ERT block, you are responsible for all of the LaTeX code. So you need to manually use `\cite{}` in this case.