# Is there a simple way to place float side by side in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

[image: float side by side]

Hello everyone. When I want to place float side by side in Lyx,which is shown in the picture, I need to add a float-figure first, then add two box, and a(maybe three)\hfill, which is very inconvenient. Is there a simple way to do this in Lyx, so I can only press one or two bottom?

Thanks!

PS: I don't want to use ERT, I want the method that is simpler than I describe above, and can preview the image in Lyx like in the picture.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible this is a duplicate? Cf. "[Using LyX, how do you put a table and a figure side by side and caption them Table XX and Figure XX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114272/46980)" | Also, some [info from LyX "walk-through"](http://www.lyx.org/Walkthrough3) if anyone is curious. | + "Side by side" [documentation for LyX](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Figures#fig-side-by-side). FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

May be you want this (captions aligned and images top-aligned)?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\floatsetup{style=plain, floatrowsep=qquad, heightadjust=object, valign=t, captionskip=2.5ex}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Float 1 on the left side}\label{flt1}}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{pepe-le-pew1}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Float 2 on the right side}\label{flt2}}
{\includegraphics{pepe-le-pew2}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\columnsep\relax}
    \kern0pt
    \centering
    \scalebox{6}{$\infty$}
    \caption{This float is on the left side}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\dimexpr\linewidth-\columnsep\relax}
    \kern0pt
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This float is on the right side}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The top alignment is achieved by option `t` of the `minipage`s together with
`\kern0pt` as first element. Option `t` aligns at the baseline for the first line/element in the `minipage`. It would be the symbol and the image, if `\kern0pt` is not given.

The hanging format of the caption text is realized by package `caption` with option `format=hang`.

The width for the `minipage`s are calculated via eTeX's `\dimexpr`. `\linewidth` is set to the current line width both inside the float environment and inside the `minipage`s.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not asking for the LaTeX code, I am asking how to do this IN LYX IN A SIMPLE WAY.

Comment: @ZhangZimou AFAIK LaTeX code can be used with LaTeX. I am not familiar with LyX. But the answer shows, that it is at least possible to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you any way, but it is not I want.

Comment: Unless you want to make them two subfigures of the same float figure, the easiest way is probably Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.