# How to solve the issue between side-by-side floats (tables) and floatrow package?

Tags: tables, floats, minipage, floatrow

I came from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101980/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-table-caption-above-figure-caption-below) where this issue was raised but could not find a straightforward solution. I have now side-by-side tables and I want to avoid the errors thrown once `floatrow` package is added to the preamble. Is there any solution to this issue or, in case not, any alternative to do side-by-side tables without sacrificing the `floatrow` package?

**MWE code:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{floatrow} % commented out otherwise throws errors (see below)
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{1\textwidth}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\hsize}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   3 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   5 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   0 &   0 &  19 &   1 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   0 &   0 &  25 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{SVMr confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmsvm}
        \vskip 1cm
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   5 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  19 &   0 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   0 &   0 &  26 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{RDA confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmrda}
        \vskip 1cm
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   3 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   4 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   0 &   0 &  19 &   0 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   1 &   0 &  26 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{PAM confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmpam}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfil
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\hsize}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   4 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  19 &   0 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   1 &   0 &  26 \\
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{PLS-LDA confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmplslda}
        \vskip 1cm
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   4 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  18 &   1 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   1 &   1 &  25 \\
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{LDA confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmlda}
        \vskip 1cm
         \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  12 &   3 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   2 &   7 &  23 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{PLS confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmpls}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfil
}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Error:

```
Package floatrow Error: Caption(s) lost
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The quickest solution is to use the `\RawFloats` command (or the `rawfloats` package option); for other possible solution, see the quote below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\RawFloats
\centering
\makebox[0pt][c]{\parbox{1\textwidth}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\hsize}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   3 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   5 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   0 &   0 &  19 &   1 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   0 &   0 &  25 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{SVMr confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmsvm}
        \vskip 1cm
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   5 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  19 &   0 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   0 &   0 &  26 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{RDA confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmrda}
        \vskip 1cm
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   3 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   4 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   0 &   0 &  19 &   0 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   1 &   0 &  26 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{PAM confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmpam}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfil
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\hsize}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   4 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  19 &   0 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   1 &   0 &  26 \\
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{PLS-LDA confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmplslda}
        \vskip 1cm
        \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   4 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  18 &   1 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   1 &   1 &  25 \\
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{LDA confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmlda}
        \vskip 1cm
         \begin{tabular}{r|rrrr}
        \toprule
          & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Reference}} \\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Predicted}  & H & P & R & Q \\ 
        \midrule
        H &   2 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        P &   0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
        R &   1 &   0 &  12 &   3 \\ 
        Q &   0 &   2 &   7 &  23 \\ 
        \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{PLS confusion matrix.}
        \label{tab:cmpls}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfil
}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The phenomenon is explained, and solutions are provided, on page 14 of the `floatrow` package documentation:

> The next example. If you put beside floats by following way:
>
> ```
> ...
> \begin{figure}
> \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
> \centering ...
> \caption{The figure caption, disappeared, ...}
> \end{minipage}\hfill
> \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
> \captionof{table}{The table caption ...}}
> \centering ...
> \end{minipage}
> \end{figure}
> ```
>
> you’ll get error message about lost caption. Here you may: 1) to put
>   table contents inside `\ttabbox` resp. the figure contents inside
>   `\ffigbox`; then both floats put inside `floatrow` environment, and, since
>   there is mixed row (it includes floats of different types, and also
>   with different caption position), put the `\killfloatstyle` command
>   before “foreign” float `\ttabbox`, and `\CenterFloatBoxes` command before
>   `floatrow` environment (see section 2.3.1 about mixed rows); or 2) to
>   restore the standard LaTeX behavior, using command `\RawFloats` or
>   package option `rawfloats` (section 2.4).

Comment: \RawFloats saved my day.