# Multiple captions under a single figure

Tags: floats, subcaption

I have a figure (lets say a picture of a couple ) for which I want two subcaptions (1 a that will be under the first half of the figure and will show the man and 1 b that will be under the second half of the picture and will show the woman).

I underline that there is only one figure that I want to caption as if there were two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example using `subfig`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{subfig}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\hspace{-1cm}%
% png from http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens#mediaviewer/File:Human.svg
\includegraphics[trim=.5cm 20cm 2.2cm 0cm, clip,height=7cm]{Human} 
\subfloat[\label{man} This is a man waving.]{\hspace{.5\linewidth}}
\subfloat[\label{woman} This is a woman.]{\hspace{.5\linewidth}}
\caption[Man a woman]{Human specimens.\label{humans}}
\end{figure}

As you can see in figure \ref{humans}, there are two types
of humans specimens: those that greet you (\ref{man}) 
and those that left the arms down (\ref{woman}).

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

If you have some conflict between `subfig` and `hyperref`, as noted by egreg cooment, you can use also the newest `subcaption` package. This example should produce the same output that above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]

\centering
\hspace{-1cm}%
% png from http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens#mediaviewer/File:Human.svg
\includegraphics[trim=.5cm 20cm 2.2cm 0cm, clip,height=7cm]{/home/fran/Human} 

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subcaption{This is a man waving.}\label{man}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subcaption{This is a woman}\label{woman}
\end{minipage}
\caption[Man a woman]{Human specimens.\label{humans}}

\end{figure}

As you can see in figure \ref{humans}, there are two types
of humans specimens: those that greet you (\ref{man}) 
and those that left the arms down (\ref{woman}).

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

If you want figure 1 and 2 (instead of 1a and 1b), simply use `\caption` instead of `\subcaption` inside the minipages (of course, then you do not need the `subcaption`package).

Comment: `subfig` may have problems with `hyperref`, probably a solution with `subcaption` would be better.

Comment: @egreg with `hyperref` loaded after `subfig` work in this case, but you are right, so I have added a mwe with `subcaption`.

Answer (score 6):

You can have as many `\caption` as you need in a `figure`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures


\begin{figure}[thp]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{man}
\caption{man}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{woman}
\caption{woman}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

text .. text .. text .. text .. text .. 
text .. text .. text .. text .. text .. 
text .. text .. text .. text .. text .. 
text .. text .. text .. text .. text .. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this is different from the accepted answer in so that this does not consider everything as a single figure with multiple subfigures but all the figures separately. Effectively, this does not work when an additional joint caption is needed for multiple figures. However, some conference templates do not allow the `subfig` package so this can work in that case.

Comment: It doesn't work without the application of the solution given here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155214/how-to-solve-the-issue-between-side-by-side-floats-tables-and-floatrow-package

Comment: @forrest I am not sure what you mean by it doesn't work, the code posted here works and answers this question, the question you reference is about floatrow which seems only partially related.

Comment: @David Carlisle Before I applied `floatrow` package with command `\RawFloats` put after `\begin{figure}` I got the message: ! Package floatrow Error: Caption(s) lost.

Comment: @forrest you could not have got a floatrow package error before you added the floatrow package.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to fake.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{figure}[h]
\refstepcounter{figure}% for label or hyperref
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline {\thefigure}{\ignorespaces man and woman}}%
\hfil\includegraphics{example-image}% old school centering

\medskip
\hfil\thefigure{ a) man}\hfil\thefigure{ b) woman}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\caption{normal caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: fake caption]