# freehand drawing in xfig or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xfig

I am trying to draw using freehand. However, I can not see how to do this in xfig. I can do this in xournalpp but I can not see how to save it as a tikz/tex document? Is it possible to do so in xfig, or in another tool that I can convert to tikz/LaTeX? I am interested in solutions that involve linux.

Comment: in `xfig`, choose "line" and paint keeping the middle mouse button clicked. But don't expect nice results...

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but do you know https://www.mathcha.io ?

Comment: For free handdrawing, I would use Inkscape

Comment: it isn't clear what you want: hand drawing and tikz seem rather opposite ends of the spectrum, you can incude hand drawn images as images https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211865/1090

Comment: thanks! had not heard of  mathcha.io. Does inkscape have a save to tex option? I will look at it, thanks!

Comment: inkscape has a tex option with pstricks, thanks!

Comment: @hpekristiansen Hi :-)...when I have read your comment I have done many smiles...I often use Mathcha :-) :-)