How to share a figure between 2 columns with paracol
I am writing a report in two languages.
Therefore, I use the package paracol to synchronize my text in columns.
I also use a \columnseprule to separate the two columns.
My problem is that within this report, I need to include some graphics.
So these images don't need to be repeated in both columns but the caption should be different for each column.
I came up with a cumbersome solution: I created a single column singleCol environment that I use in the left column and I use a phantom in the right column to have the same spacing.
It is work-ish: the spacing is still not perfect, and figure counters are not correct...
But I still have one problem.
The column rule separator is overlaying my figure, despite the that I change the size of the rule to 0 within this environment.

So as a more general question: how can I share a single graphic for 2 columns with their own caption in a float environment with paracol ?
Or as a specific question (if my solution is retained), how to remove the \columnseprule locally within a paracol environment ?
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \usepackage{graphicx,float}
  \usepackage{paracol}
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
     \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

     \makeatletter
     \newenvironment{singleCol}{% at begining of the env
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.0pt}
        \vskip\intextsep
        \noindent\minipage{\textwidth}
     }% body goes here
     {% at the end of the env
        \endminipage\hskip-\textwidth
     }% 
     \makeatother
  
\begin{document} 

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
     For several days in succession fragments of a defeated army had passed through the town. 
     
     They were mere disorganized bands, not disciplined forces. 
     The men wore long, dirty beards and tattered uniforms; they advanced in listless fashion, without a flag, without a leader.
     All seemed exhausted, worn out, incapable of thought or resolve, marching onward merely by force of habit, and dropping to the ground with fatigue the moment they halted.
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     Pendant plusieurs jours de suite des lambeaux d'armée en déroute avaient traversé la ville. 

     Ce n'était point de la troupe, mais des hordes débandées. 
     Les hommes avaient la barbe longue et sale, des uniformes en guenilles, et ils avançaient d'une allure molle, 
     sans drapeau, sans régiment. Tous semblaient accablés, éreintés, incapables d'une pensée ou d'une résolution,   marchant seulement par habitude, et tombant de fatigue sitôt qu'ils s'arrêtaient. 
  \end{rightcolumn}

  \begin{figure*}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
     \caption{caption of figure1}
  \end{figure*}

  \begin{leftcolumn}
     One saw, in particular, many enlisted men, pea\-ceful citizens, men who lived quietly on their income, bending beneath the weight of their rifles; and little active volunteers,   easily frightened but full of enthusiasm, as eager to attack as they were ready to take to flight; and amid these, a sprinkling of red-breeched soldiers,       the pitiful remnant of a division cut down in a great battle; somber artillerymen, side by side with nondescript foot-soldiers; and, here and there, the gleaming helmet of a heavy-footed dragoon who had difficulty in keeping up with the quicker pace of the soldiers of the line.
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     On voyait surtout des mobilisés, gens pacifiques, rentiers tranquilles, pliant sous le poids du fusil; des petits moblots alertes, faciles à l'épouvante et prom\-pts à l'enthousiasme, prêts à l'attaque comme à la fuite; puis, au milieu d'eux, quelques culottes rouges, débris d'une division moulue dans une gran\-de bataille; des artilleurs sombres alignés avec des fantassins divers; et, parfois, le casque brillant d'un dragon au pied pesant qui suivait avec peine la marche plus légère des lignards.
  \end{rightcolumn}

  \begin{leftcolumn*}
     Legions of irregulars with high---sounding na\-mes ``Avengers of Defeat'', ``Citizens of the Tomb'', ``Breth\-ren in Death''---passed in their turn, looking like banditti. 
  \end{leftcolumn*}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     Des légions de francs---tireurs aux appellations héroïques : « les Vengeurs de la Défaite, les Citoyens de la Tombe,
     les Partageurs de la Mort » --- passaient à leur tour, avec des airs de bandits.
  \end{rightcolumn}


  \begin{leftcolumn}
     \begin{figure}[b]
        \begin{singleCol}
           \centering
           \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
        \end{singleCol}
        \caption{caption of figure3}
     \end{figure}%
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     \begin{figure}[b]
        \phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
        \caption{caption de la figure3}
     \end{figure}%
  \end{rightcolumn}


  \begin{leftcolumn*}
     Their leaders, former drapers or grain merchants, or tallow or soap chandlers---warriors by force of circumstances, officers by reason of their mustachios or their money---covered with weapons, flannel and gold lace, spoke in an impressive manner,
     discussed plans of campaign,and behaved as though they alone bore the fortunes of dying France on their braggart shoulders; 
     though, in truth, they frequently were afraid of their own men---scoundrels often brave beyond measure, but pillagers and debauchees.
  \end{leftcolumn*}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     Leurs chefs, anciens commerçants en draps ou en graines, ex--marchands de suif ou de savon, guerriers de circonstance, 
     nommés officiers pour leurs écus ou la longueur de leurs moustaches, couverts d'armes, de flanelle et de galons, 
     parlaient d'une voix retentissante, discutaient plans de campagne, et prétendaient soutenir seuls la France agonisante sur leurs épaules de fanfarons;
     mais ils redoutaient parfois leurs propres soldats, gens de sac et de corde, souvent braves à outrance, pillards et débauchés.
  \end{rightcolumn}
  
  \begin{table*}
     \centering
     table1
     \caption{à table}
  \end{table*}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
%EoF


I assume you want to have an English caption on the left side and a French caption on the right side, both with the same figure number.
A new command was defined here to mimic the behavior of \caption, thus allowing you to have both captions under a single figure and build the corresponding list of figures.
\DoubleCaptionFig{<left caption>}{<right caption>}{<figure name>}{<label>}



% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

\newcommand{\DoubleCaptionFig}[4]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211767/161015
\end{paracol}
    \begin{figure*}
        \refstepcounter{figure}\label{#4}%
        \noindent%
        \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces (eng) #1}}%
        \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}{\ignorespaces (fr) #2}}%
        \centering%
        \includegraphics{#3}% 
                
        \medskip%
        Fig.\ \thefigure{\enspace  #1}\hfil \hspace*{0.5\columnsep} Fig.\ \thefigure{\enspace  #2}%
    \end{figure*}
    \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy%
    }

\begin{document} 
    
        \listoffigures
        \newpage
    
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \sloppy
        \begin{leftcolumn}
            For several days in succession fragments of a defeated army had passed through the town (see figure \ref{fig:a}). 
            
            They were mere disorganized bands, not disciplined forces. 
            The men wore long, dirty beards and tattered uniforms; they advanced in listless fashion, without a flag, without a leader.
            All seemed exhausted, worn out, incapable of thought or resolve, marching onward merely by force of habit, and dropping to the ground with fatigue the moment they halted.
        \end{leftcolumn}
        \begin{rightcolumn}
            Pendant plusieurs jours de suite des lambeaux d'armée en déroute avaient traversé la ville (voir figure \ref{fig:a}).
            
            Ce n'était point de la troupe, mais des hordes débandées. 
            Les hommes avaient la barbe longue et sale, des uniformes en guenilles, et ils avançaient d'une allure molle, 
            sans drapeau, sans régiment. Tous semblaient accablés, éreintés, incapables d'une pensée ou d'une résolution,   marchant seulement par habitude, et tombant de fatigue sitôt qu'ils s'arrêtaient. 
        \end{rightcolumn}
    
    \DoubleCaptionFig{A defeated army}{Une armée vaincue}{example-image-a}{fig:a}

        \begin{leftcolumn}
            One saw, in particular, many enlisted men, pea\-ceful citizens, men who lived quietly on their income, bending beneath the weight of their rifles; and little active volunteers,   easily frightened but full of enthusiasm, as eager to attack as they were ready to take to flight; and amid these, a sprinkling of red-breeched soldiers,       the pitiful remnant of a division cut down in a great battle; somber artillerymen, side by side with nondescript foot-soldiers; and, here and there, the gleaming helmet of a heavy-footed dragoon who had difficulty in keeping up with the quicker pace of the soldiers of the line.
        \end{leftcolumn}
        \begin{rightcolumn}
            On voyait surtout des mobilisés, gens pacifiques, rentiers tranquilles, pliant sous le poids du fusil; des petits moblots alertes, faciles à l'épouvante et prom\-pts à l'enthousiasme, prêts à l'attaque comme à la fuite; puis, au milieu d'eux, quelques culottes rouges, débris d'une division moulue dans une gran\-de bataille; des artilleurs sombres alignés avec des fantassins divers; et, parfois, le casque brillant d'un dragon au pied pesant qui suivait avec peine la marche plus légère des lignards.
        \end{rightcolumn}
        
        \begin{leftcolumn*}
            Legions of irregulars (see figure \ref{fig:b}) with high---sounding na\-mes ``Avengers of Defeat'', ``Citizens of the Tomb'', ``Bre\-thren in Death''---passed in their turn, looking like banditti. 
        \end{leftcolumn*}
        \begin{rightcolumn}
            Des légions de francs---tireurs aux appellations héroïques : « les Vengeurs de la Défaite, les Citoyens de la Tombe,    les Partageurs de la Mort » --- passaient à leur tour, avec des airs de bandits (voir figure \ref{fig:b}).
        \end{rightcolumn}

        \DoubleCaptionFig{Legions of irregulars}{Des légions d'irréguliers}{example-image-b}{fig:b}

        \begin{leftcolumn}
            Their leaders, former drapers or grain merchants, or tallow or soap chan\-dlers---warriors by force of circumstan\-ces, officers by reason of their mustachios or their money---covered with weapons, flannel and gold lace, spoke in an impressive manner,
            discussed plans of campaign,and behaved as though they alone bore the fortunes of dying France on their braggart shoulders; 
            though, in truth, they frequently were afraid of their own men---scoundrels often brave beyond measure, but pillagers and debauchees.
        \end{leftcolumn}
        \begin{rightcolumn}
            Leurs chefs, anciens commerçants en draps ou en graines, ex--marchands de suif ou de savon, guerriers de circonstance, 
            nommés officiers pour leurs écus ou la longueur de leurs moustaches, couverts d'armes, de flanelle et de galons, 
            parlaient d'une voix retentissante, discutaient plans de campagne, et prétendaient soutenir seuls la France agonisante sur leurs épaules de fanfarons;
            mais ils redoutaient parfois leurs propres soldats, gens de sac et de corde, souvent braves à outrance, pillards et débauchés.
        \end{rightcolumn}
        
        \begin{table*}
            \centering
            table1
            \caption{à table}
        \end{table*}
        
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}

If you want to have floating figures, remove \end{paracol} and \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy from the \DoubleCaptionFig definition.

Not less cumbersome, but it seems to work :)

Outside paracol you ony need figure, not figure*.  I suspect this is done automatically, since figure* does not support [h].

Paracol supports adding full width inserts between column changes using the optional arguments for leftcolumn* and rightcolumn*.  However, floats behave strangely there.  Also, you cannot nest optional arguments (see ] inside an optional argument).
This uses the [H] option from the float package.  Note the use of [{ ... }] to allow optional arguments inside.  The advantage of this approach is that everything is in one figure and cannot be separated.  There is no dividing line betwwen the left and right captions, although one can always add one.
\documentclass{article} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \usepackage{graphicx,float}
  \usepackage{paracol}
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
     \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\globalcounter{figure}
\globalcounter{table}
\usepackage{float}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  
\begin{document} 

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \sloppy
  \begin{leftcolumn}
     For several days in succession fragments of a defeated army had passed through the town. 
     
     They were mere disorganized bands, not disciplined forces. 
     The men wore long, dirty beards and tattered uniforms; they advanced in listless fashion, without a flag, without a leader.
     All seemed exhausted, worn out, incapable of thought or resolve, marching onward merely by force of habit, and dropping to the ground with fatigue the moment they halted.
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     Pendant plusieurs jours de suite des lambeaux d'armée en déroute avaient traversé la ville. 

     Ce n'était point de la troupe, mais des hordes débandées. 
     Les hommes avaient la barbe longue et sale, des uniformes en guenilles, et ils avançaient d'une allure molle, 
     sans drapeau, sans régiment. Tous semblaient accablés, éreintés, incapables d'une pensée ou d'une résolution,   marchant seulement par habitude, et tombant de fatigue sitôt qu'ils s'arrêtaient. 
  \end{rightcolumn}
 
\begin{leftcolumn*}[{
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \setlength{\columnwidth}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
      \caption{left caption}
      \addtocounter{figure}{-1}% repeat
    \end{minipage}\hfill%\rule[-2ex]{0.4pt}{\baselineskip}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
      \caption{right caption}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}
}]
     One saw, in particular, many enlisted men, pea\-ceful citizens, men who lived quietly on their income, bending beneath the weight of their rifles; and little active volunteers,   easily frightened but full of enthusiasm, as eager to attack as they were ready to take to flight; and amid these, a sprinkling of red-breeched soldiers,       the pitiful remnant of a division cut down in a great battle; somber artillerymen, side by side with nondescript foot-soldiers; and, here and there, the gleaming helmet of a heavy-footed dragoon who had difficulty in keeping up with the quicker pace of the soldiers of the line.
  \end{leftcolumn*}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     On voyait surtout des mobilisés, gens pacifiques, rentiers tranquilles, pliant sous le poids du fusil; des petits moblots alertes, faciles à l'épouvante et prom\-pts à l'enthousiasme, prêts à l'attaque comme à la fuite; puis, au milieu d'eux, quelques culottes rouges, débris d'une division moulue dans une gran\-de bataille; des artilleurs sombres alignés avec des fantassins divers; et, parfois, le casque brillant d'un dragon au pied pesant qui suivait avec peine la marche plus légère des lignards.
  \end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}


This uses normal left and right column \captions (no global counters).
\documentclass{article} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \usepackage{graphicx,float}
  \usepackage{paracol}
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
     \setlength{\columnsep}{2em}
 
\begin{document} 

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \sloppy
  \begin{leftcolumn}
     For several days in succession fragments of a defeated army had passed through the town. 
     
     They were mere disorganized bands, not disciplined forces. 
     The men wore long, dirty beards and tattered uniforms; they advanced in listless fashion, without a flag, without a leader.
     All seemed exhausted, worn out, incapable of thought or resolve, marching onward merely by force of habit, and dropping to the ground with fatigue the moment they halted.
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     Pendant plusieurs jours de suite des lambeaux d'armée en déroute avaient traversé la ville. 

     Ce n'était point de la troupe, mais des hordes débandées. 
     Les hommes avaient la barbe longue et sale, des uniformes en guenilles, et ils avançaient d'une allure molle, 
     sans drapeau, sans régiment. Tous semblaient accablés, éreintés, incapables d'une pensée ou d'une résolution,   marchant seulement par habitude, et tombant de fatigue sitôt qu'ils s'arrêtaient. 
  \end{rightcolumn}
 
\begin{leftcolumn*}[{\centering% or \noindent
    \vskip\intextsep
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \vskip\intextsep% put a gap before the \colseprule starts
}]
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \vskip-2\intextsep% remove excess space
    \caption{left caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{leftcolumn*}
\begin{rightcolumn}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \vskip-2\intextsep
    \caption{right caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{rightcolumn}

\begin{leftcolumn*}
     One saw, in particular, many enlisted men, pea\-ceful citizens, men who lived quietly on their income, bending beneath the weight of their rifles; and little active volunteers,   easily frightened but full of enthusiasm, as eager to attack as they were ready to take to flight; and amid these, a sprinkling of red-breeched soldiers,       the pitiful remnant of a division cut down in a great battle; somber artillerymen, side by side with nondescript foot-soldiers; and, here and there, the gleaming helmet of a heavy-footed dragoon who had difficulty in keeping up with the quicker pace of the soldiers of the line.
  \end{leftcolumn*}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
     On voyait surtout des mobilisés, gens pacifiques, rentiers tranquilles, pliant sous le poids du fusil; des petits moblots alertes, faciles à l'épouvante et prom\-pts à l'enthousiasme, prêts à l'attaque comme à la fuite; puis, au milieu d'eux, quelques culottes rouges, débris d'une division moulue dans une gran\-de bataille; des artilleurs sombres alignés avec des fantassins divers; et, parfois, le casque brillant d'un dragon au pied pesant qui suivait avec peine la marche plus légère des lignards.
  \end{rightcolumn}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}


Your solution is interesting for the floating aspect of the environment. However it misses the multi-column caption aspect of the question.

I was wondering what that was alll about.
