# Unexpected table/figure reference

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, floatrow

**Code**

Consider the follwing example:

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
  \ffigbox{
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{image1}%
  }{
    \caption{Figure caption.}
    \label{fig:1}
  }
  \capbtabbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{
      l
      S[table-format = 2]
    }
     \toprule
      Næring~[\qty{1}{\g}] & {Energi~(\unit{\kJ})} \\
     \midrule
      Protein              & 17 \\[0.5ex]
      Fedtstof             & 38 \\[0.5ex]
      Kulhydrat            & 17 \\[0.5ex]
      Alkohol              & 30 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }{
    \caption{Table caption.}
    \label{tbl:1}
  }
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\autoref{tbl:1}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Question**

How to I make a reference to the table and not to the figure?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155223

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you Barbara. I'm not sure exactly what to look for in the other answer so can I maybe make you write an answer for my question? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Svend -- I've never tried this myself, so what I was searching for was questions that cited `ffigbox` and needed references.  Looking through the manual for `floatrow`, it looks like `\ttabbox` should give a recognizable "table", and `\floatsetup[table]{capposition=bottom}` to set a bottom caption.  This is just a guess, based on the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `\autoref` does not use `\@currentlabelname` but rather uses `\@currentHref` to get the counter name.  However, every caption in a figure uses the same `\@currentHref`, which is set at the top of the figure.

One can use `\capstart` from the [`hypcap`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hypcap) package to add another `\@currentHref` with the desired `\@captype` (table).

I didn't use [`floatrow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) mostly to make sure it wasn't the source of the problem (which it often is).

```
\documentclass[danish]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]% #1 = figure or table
  {\def\@captype{#1}}
  
\newcommand{\setlabelname}[1]{\def\@currentlabelname{#1}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{table}{1}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.2\textwidth]{image1}%
    \caption{Figure caption.}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
  \setcaptype{table}\capstart
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[b]{
      l
      S[table-format = 2]
    }
     \toprule
      Næring~[\qty{1}{\g}] & {Energi~(\unit{\kJ})} \\
     \midrule
      Protein              & 17 \\[0.5ex]
      Fedtstof             & 38 \\[0.5ex]
      Kulhydrat            & 17 \\[0.5ex]
      Alkohol              & 30 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table caption.}
    \setlabelname{notused}
    \label{tbl:1}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\autoref{tbl:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at it when I get home from work and then report back whether or not it fixed my problem.

Comment: I regard putting the counter name into \@currentHref instead of \@currentlabelname to be a bad decision.  I would go the other way and fill every \@currentHref with auto.1 auto.2 etc.  All \@currentHref needs to do is generate unique labels which are compatible with (but unlikely to be duplicated by) \hypertarget.