# How to use cleveref's \namecref for unnumbered sections?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

As I don't want my sections ... paragraphs to stay unnumbered, I wrote `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`. With `cleveref` I cannot refer to unnumbered sections as "section" at all.

To be more clear: I defined a new ref-format `\RenewDocumentCommand\fullref{m}{\namecref{#1} \nameref{#1} \vpageref{#1}}`, which should give something like "section *sectiontitle* on page 2" or "subsection *sectiontitle* on page 4.

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german,final]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[german,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand\fullref{m}{\namecref{#1} \nameref{#1}
  \vpageref{#1}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % <---
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{I'm Section}
\label{sec:section}
bla

see \namecref{sec:subsubsection}

see \fullref{sec:subsubsection}
\newpage
\subsection{I'm Subsection}
\label{sec:subsection}
bla

bla

see \namecref{sec:section}

see \fullref{sec:section}

see \namecref{sec:subsection}

see \fullref{sec:subsection}
\newpage
\subsubsection{I'm Child of Subsection}
\label{sec:subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could try \autoref instead of \namecref.

Comment: `\label` only stores 4 values in  the aux file: `\@currentlabel`, `\thepage`, `\@currentlabelname` and `\@currentHref`.  The section title is stored in `\@currentlabelname` which is a missuse of the entry IMHO.

Comment: @JohnKormylo \@currentlabelname is meant for the title, it is not a misuse.

Comment: @JohnKormylo sorry I don't know what you mean. \@currentlabelname is imho used since more than 20 years by nameref, and \@currentcounter was never saved by \label (but you can save it e.g. with zref)

Comment: OTOH, I have seen people get the counter name by editing `\currentHref`.  This doesn't always work (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643473/unexpected-table-figure-reference/643489?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C10.6660#643489).

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, autoref tries to guess the counter name by looking at currentHref, and that doesn't always work. But with the new label implementation you can now insert a hook to properly store the counter name and reference it e.g. with zref. At sometime I will perhaps try to adapt autoref to use the new option.

Comment: One could do like the subcaption package and create two \newlabel commands for each \label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following. This requires a current LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\RenewDocumentCommand\fullref{m}{\namecref{#1} \nameref{#1}
  \vpageref{#1}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % <---

\makeatletter
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/@sect/before}{\def\cref@currentlabel{[#1][??][??]??}}
\makeatother

\crefname{section}{section}{sections}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefname{subsubsection}{subsubsection}{subsections}
\begin{document}

\section{I'm Section}\label{sec:section}
bla

see \namecref{sec:subsubsection}, \cref{sec:subsubsection}

see \fullref{sec:subsubsection}
\subsection{I'm Subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
bla
see \namecref{sec:section}

see \fullref{sec:section}

see \namecref{sec:subsection}

see \fullref{sec:subsection}
\subsubsection{I'm Child of Subsection}
\label{sec:subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]