# Table next to figure using subfig

Tags: subfloats

I'm trying typeset a table next to a figure using `subfig`, but I cannot get them to align properly. I have found a similar(/identical) question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/figure-and-table-side-by-side-in-subfloats), but the solutions/suggestions do not seem to be applicable in my case as (a) I am using a fully-updated TeX Live 2013 distribution; and (b) I do not make use of the `hyperref` package.

Since the journal I am preparing this document for kind of forces `subfig` onto me, I would rather solve this without having to resort to using a different subfloat package.

The issue:

[image]

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Figure]{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\label{subfig:black-hole}}%
  \qquad
  \subfloat[Table]{%
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline
      C1 & C2 \\ \hline
      A  & A \\
      B  & B \\
      C  & C \\
      D  & D \\
      E  & E \\
      F  & F \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{subtbl:the-table}
  }
  \caption{Figure and table.}
  \label{fig:figure-and-table}
\end{figure}

\noindent Look at Figure~\ref{fig:figure-and-table}; it includes both a figure (Figure~\ref{subfig:black-hole}) and a table (Table~\ref{subtbl:the-table}).
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Just to elaborate on my own silliness: I had already tried `[b]` but I didn't realise that it actually helped. On the top is what I got and on the bottom is what I thought I should get:

```
  Figure    Table

 ---------
 |       |
 |       |
y|       |  
 |       |  C1 C2
 |       |  -----
 ---------  A  B
     x      -----
   (a)       (b) <- The subcaptions


 ---------  
 |       |
 |       |
y|       |  C1 C2  
 |       |  -----
 |       |  A  B
 ---------  -----
     x      
   (a)       (b) <- The subcaptions
```

So I thought that the bottom of the table would be aligned with the x axis instead of the x label, which I assume is impossible without some manual work. I'll just keep looking for a way to do that and ask again if I'm lost. `:-)`

Comment: It actually does! I had tried that, but not in the MWE. I thought `[b]` hadn't helped because the table was aligned with the x label instead instead with the x axis. But that is a different question altogether I guess. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what type of alignment you would like.

Comment: @AndrewSwann See my edit for an illustration of my silliness. `:-)`

Comment: You can surround the `tabular` with a `\raisebox{0.5cm}{...}`, with `0.5cm` replaced by a suitable height.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Yes, thanks. I already solved it by moving the x label at the top. No manual work required that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the option `[b]` to align the table.

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
```

and the result is

[image]