# Different float types side-by-side

Tags: floats, positioning, captions

I'm familiar with using minipages inside a float to effectively place two floats side-by-side, but is there a way to do this with different float types?  Eg a Figure and a Scheme (chemscheme)?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This question is very similar to the one lockstep pointed you to. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% delete demo later
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
 \begin{floatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{normalimage}}
    {\caption{My figure}\label{foo}}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{chemfig}}%
    {\captionof{scheme}{My chem scheme}\label{bar}}
 \end{floatrow}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Simply use one float environment with two `minipage`s inside. Then use the normal `\caption` for the one float and `\captionof{<other type>}{<caption text>}` for the other. This needs either the `caption` or the `capt-of` package.

---

The issue with `scheme` from `chemscheme` is that it isn't a normal float but (by default) defined using `floatrow` which doesn't support code like above (I get a 'caption lost' error). The alternate definition over the `float` package doesn't work either because it always places the caption on its own and not part of the actual content, so it breaks out of the `minipage`.

I now found the following solution which undoes some stuff from the `floatrow` package and define `scheme` the same way as `figure`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% 'demo' option only to not require actually images for this example file
\usepackage{capt-of}% or 'caption'
\usepackage{chemscheme}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\scheme{\@float{scheme}}
\let\endscheme\endfigure
\makeatother

\begin{scheme}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{normalimage}
        \captionof{figure}{My figure}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{chemfig}
        \caption{My chem scheme}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

However, putting `\captionof{scheme}` into a `figure` environment still doesn't work ('caption lost' error again).

You would recommend to wait until someone which knows `floatrow` better than me posts an answer.

Comment: I downvoted this because the usage of \RawFloats inside this scheme environment would be a much cleaner (and documented) solution. I'm always angry about such patches since after using three to six such "solutions" the user gets into trouble and is asking package authors (like me) for help via e-mail afterwards.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: No problem. It is a hack after all. Can you tell me why `scheme` and other floats are not defined *exactly* the same way than `figure` and `table`? It is a shame that e.g. `float` doesn't allow for arbitrary content.

Comment: Yes, it's a shame. AFAIK `scheme` is simply not defined like `figure` and `table` because it uses the `floatrow` package for defining it. The `floatrow` package does not do it this way because it was designed as an extension to the `float` package first. And the `float` package follows the idea of having "float styles" but forget to offer a macro to define new non-styled floating environments.

Comment: `KOMA-Script` and the `caption` package are offering macros for defining new floating environments which behave like `figure` and `table`, but IMHO it would be overkill to include them for just defining new floating environments. Maybe I should split that functionality into a new package called `newfloat` or similar?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: I had the same idea about a `newfloat` package. However, a CTAN search gave me Joseph Wright's `trivfloat` package which seems to do this.

Comment: No, `trivfloat` is just using the `float` package, offering an easier syntax for beginners.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Ah, thanks! I misread the abstract of the package.

Comment: I'm just extracting `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` from my `caption3` package to a `newfloat` package...

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Ah, I just did the same with the LaTeX core code: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/newfloat :-) But I don't have an issue with not using it. Your existing code should be much better tested.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do this? ;-) Such package needs to be adapted to various document classes and packages, e.g. for having a skip between list entries on `\chapter` boundaries. And I'm used to such package hell. No, I'm not saying that I'm tougher than you (in fact I'm quite a wimp), but I already have all code for this (except for memoir, but I'm just adapting it with help of Lars Madsen), and if I had known all this is the past, I would have never released a `caption` package at all.