# LaTeX: Numero sign ('№')

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

Is there a [numero sign ('№')](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_sign) available to LaTeX?

Currently using `N\textsuperscript{\underline{o}}` which is typographically a little Frankensteinesque:

[image]

Comment: You don't like `textcomp`s `\textnumero`?

Comment: (Apologies, after asking I double-checked the symbols list and found the answer. Not sure what the policy is for this.)

Comment: The policy is to retoactively add a +50 bounty to one of my answers. ;-)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions ;)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Apologies. `\textnumero` is in the [comprehensive symbols list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). I thought I had checked it already. It's in the `textcomp` package.

It's very pretty:

[image]

Comment: Related: For non-`textcomp` № in unicode and legacy fonts, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375888/to-make-the-numero-sign-would-n-textsuperscript-underline-scriptsize-o-be-a/613930#613930