# Custom command in \maketitle redefinition

Tags: titles

I want to redefine `\maketitle` the way it contains my custom command. I have a home assignment and I'd like to put `\@variant` command or something to be able to set it later as with `\@author` and `\@title`.

Here is my redefinition

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{2ex}
        \textbf{\huge \textsc{\@title}}
        \vspace{3ex}\\
        \Large \@author\\
        \hrulefill\\
        \vspace{1ex}
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother
```

Then in preambule I have such commands:

```
\title{My beautiful title}
\author{My Name}
```

And I want to write `\varian{number}` after `\author` and get it right under my name.

Here is the definition of the `\variant`:

```
\newcommand{\variant}[1]{Variant №\:#1}
```

And it should be something like that:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{2ex}
        \textbf{\huge \textsc{\@title}}
        \vspace{3ex}\\
        \Large \@author\\
        \small \@variant\\
        \hrulefill\\
        \vspace{1ex}
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

\title{My beautiful title}
\author{My Name}
\variant{number}
```

**Important:** I don't want to hard code it straight away in the redefinition, I want to make everything fancy. And I don't want to use any additional packages.

Comment: For the future, remember to provide a *complete* [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\variant` command can be defined as:

```
\newcommand\variant[1]{\renewcommand\@variant{Variant \textnumero\,#1}}
\newcommand\@variant{}
```

I added the`textcomp` package to typeset the `№` [symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40564/177).
Otherwise this character is not recognized.
If you don't want to add this package, maybe change the Number identification.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\variant[1]{\renewcommand\@variant{Variant \textnumero\,#1}}
\newcommand\@variant{}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}
        \vspace{2ex}
        \textbf{\huge \textsc{\@title}}
        \vspace{3ex}\\
        \Large \@author\\
        \small \@variant\\
        \hrulefill\\
        \vspace{1ex}
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{My beautiful title}
\author{My Name}
\variant{number}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!
Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Also the other answer is worth [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) ;)

Comment: Can you explain how it works exactly?
Why do you need to define `\@variant` empty and then redefine it? Can't it be defined right into `\variant` definition?

Comment: @antshar It's not a good idea use `\newcommand` inside such a macro, so you need to use `\renewcommand` if you are doing this using only LaTeX constructs. Since `\renewcommand` assumes the existence of the command, you need to define it initially with `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 0):

The `titling` package provides a nice interface for modifying the title. It provides commands to insert material after each of the required elements.

Here's a simple way to add your `\variant` to the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\variant}[1]{\def\myvariant{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{\large\centering\par  Variant No: \myvariant}
\title{A title}
\variant{A variant number}
\author{An author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: At the end of the question I asked to offer the solution without any additional packages.
Nevertheless, thank you for the answer, I'll take into accout such a method.

Comment: @antshar Yes, I understand. I think the "no extra packages" requirement is overrated. If you are writing your own document class or package, then modifying large chunks of code from the core classes may be appropriate, but if you're doing this within an individual document, this is a much cleaner approach. I'll leave it here for others.