# A figure and table side by side

Tags: floats, positioning

I tried to insert  my plot in many ways in this code but did not work. Can someone kindly please tell me where can I insert my plot below code; especially I dont understand  whats `\rule{}`  is also.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) I removed your name as it is given in the right hand corner :) I also removed the thanks- it may seem a little strange, but we like to keep this site more like "Q&A" rather than a forum :) Welcome!

Comment: have you seen [Table and Figure side-by-side with independent captions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850) ?

Comment: Yes, the above code is already been taken the link you provide me..

Comment: i tried to use \includegraphics{plot4} instead of \rule but it didnt work :(

Comment: can you give more details- what kind of error message? is `plot4` in the appropriate directory?

Comment: Error is i can't see my graph. Above code must be working properly for others but somehow  not for me! Do you know above code where do you normally put your graph(for example plot4 command)? Also definitely i use the same directory with my latex template

Comment: To answer your question of what is `\rule`, it is a command to make a black rectangle.  It is used to create a figure sized box, when one doesn't have an actual figure handy for a piece of sample code.  In your actual code, you would replace the `\rule{}{}` with something like `\includegraphics[scale=x.x]{graphic-filename}`

Comment: Steven thank you so much. Its working now :)