# Make a minipage float

Tags: floats, positioning, minipage

I am using the `minipage` environment to put a table and figure next to each other. Now I would like this to 'float' like a normal figure or table, such that LaTeX decides where to put it (using the [htb] options). After some googling, I found that the `minipage` environment is not a floating one, so it will always be inserted in the same location as the code. This is not always the nicest solution.

Is there a way to prevent/circumvent this, such that also a minipage is treated like a float?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `floatrow` package, and it would be a good option, if my document class hadn't used the `float` package. I'm getting errors that say they're not compatible.

Comment: There were other possible solutions there as well. You could use Thorsten's last alternative, and replace the outer `minipage` with `figure`.

Comment: @Jelle Since the `floatrow` package is (nearly) compatible to the commands offered by the `float` package, you could replace the `float` package by the `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an existing float such as `figure` instead of `minipage` to hold your side by side figure and table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{capt-of}


\makeatletter
%\let\ftype@table\ftype@figure
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\clearpage


\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}XXX
\captionof{figure}{fff}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\captionof{table}{ttt}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

aaa

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}YYY
\captionof{figure}{fff}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\captionof{table}{ttt}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

aaa

\begin{table}\rule{2cm}{7cm}\quad\rule{2cm}{7cm}
\caption{TTT}
\end{table}

aaa

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}XXX
\captionof{figure}{fff}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\rule{2cm}{1cm}
\captionof{table}{ttt}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

aaa

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}YYY
\captionof{figure}{fff}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\rule{2cm}{3cm}
\captionof{table}{ttt}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

aaa


\end{document}
```

Note however that while this works, LaTeX sees this as a *figure* while floating boxes around so only keeps it in sequence with *figures* this means that if some tables are on their own in a table environment they may float out of sequence with tables that are in a figure environment.

The end result is that the list of tables looks like

[image]

The simplest fix is to uncomment the commented line so that figures and tables are kept in the same sequence. This has the disadvantage that LaTeX won't then float any figure past any table so it gives less flexibility in the algorithm but it has the advantage of working and placing teh floats in the correct order as shown in the lists:

[image]