# How to manipulate width and position of items inside floatrow

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, floatrow

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions/6869#6869) by @lockstep I learned, how to put figure and table side by side:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
%tried \ffigbox[0.5\linewidth]{%
\ffigbox{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't understand, how to set the width of every column and align the table/figure left, center, right.

In the docs I found, that \ffigbox has width parameter and tried 0.5\linewidth, making each column half of the page. But that's all I achieved so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "left" alignment of the table? So that the table as well as it's caption is left-aligned?

Comment: @Werner Align the table or figure to the left side of the column.

Comment: @user4035 just the table/figure or also the caption?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The caption must be aligned by the center of the table or figure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the best way to illustrate how the different commands work is to use some auxiliary boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newcommand\MyBox[2][red!70!black]{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fcolorbox{#1}{white}{#2}}}

\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\MyBox[blue]{\begin{floatrow}
\MyBox{\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}}%
\MyBox{\capbtabbox[\FBwidth]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\MyBox[blue]{\begin{floatrow}
\MyBox{\ffigbox[8cm]{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}}%
\MyBox{\capbtabbox[7cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\MyBox[blue]{\begin{floatrow}
\MyBox{\ffigbox[8cm]{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}}\qquad%
\MyBox{\capbtabbox[7cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `floatrow` environment (with default settings) reserves a box having a width equal to the entire `\textwidth` (the blue boxes in the example); the content will be centered by default.

The optional argument for `ffigbox` and `captabbox` allows to specify the width to be used for the content of each of these commands (the red boxes in the example); `\FBwidth` will give you the natural width (see first example), but you can select any other values (second and third example). In the third example a `\qquad` space was further introduced between the image and the table.

To control the position of the object inside its box, the package offers the `objectset` key which admits values similiar to those of justification for `\captionsetup` from the caption package; a little example using `objectset=raggedright` and the same settings for the width as as in the second example from the code above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newcommand\MyBox[2][red!70!black]{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fcolorbox{#1}{white}{#2}}}

\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}


\thisfloatsetup{objectset=raggedright}
\begin{figure}
\MyBox[blue]{\begin{floatrow}
\MyBox{\ffigbox[8cm]{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}}\qquad%
\MyBox{\capbtabbox[7cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, of course, you can use all the power of `floatrow` with all the power of `caption` to have, for example, both objects and captions raggedright or raggedleft:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\newcommand\MyBox[2][red!70!black]{{%
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\fcolorbox{#1}{white}{#2}}}

\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{objectset=raggedright}
\begin{figure}
\MyBox[blue]{\begin{floatrow}
\MyBox{\ffigbox[8cm]{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}}\qquad%
\MyBox{\capbtabbox[7cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}

\thisfloatsetup{objectset=raggedleft}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off,justification=raggedleft}
\begin{figure}
\MyBox[blue]{\begin{floatrow}
\MyBox{\ffigbox[8cm]{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}}\qquad%
\MyBox{\capbtabbox[7cm]{%
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}}
\end{floatrow}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]