# How to label Table and Figure side-by-side with combined caption

Tags: floats, captions

Adapted from Thorsten Donigs answer in [Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions)

The Caption correctly numbers the figure and table but how does the correct setup of the labels independently for the figure and the table for referencing in the text work in this example?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2  \&  \tablename~\thetable}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
       \rule{3cm}{3cm}
    \caption{pic1}
\end{figure}

\autoref{tab:table123} %will give Figure 2 instead of Table 1.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
       \rule{3cm}{3cm}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}\hline
      Table head & Table head \\ \hline
      Some values & Some values \\
      Some values & Some values \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionlistentry[table]{entry for table}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
    \caption{some caption for both.}
    \label{tab:table123}
    \label{fig:pic2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `captionlistentry` probably increases the table counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to label the point at which the relevant counter is incremented, and tell hyperref you are labelling a table even though it is a figure environment.

```
\captionlistentry[figure]{entry for figure}
\label{fig:figure345}
\captionlistentry[table]{entry for table}
{\makeatletter\edef\@currentHref{table.caption.\the\c@table}\label{tab:table123}}
```

Comment: `hyperref` is missing ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel yes I know, but people should test their MWE:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: oops. (edited above now). the counter is correct now, but it still says "Figure 1" instead of "Table 1"

Comment: @Dircandis see update

Comment: cool, it partly works! but the hyperref-link is not working

Comment: @Dircandis I give up, wait for Heiko to pass by:-)

Comment: np, i also get a "Warning: Multiply defined labels"

Comment: @Dircandis did you copy rather than move the `\label` If you just have one for the table and one for the figure they should not clash

Comment: i deleted the "\captionlistentry[figure]{entry for figure}" because it gave an another increment of the figure number that is not needed in this case. the label is actually just there once..

Comment: @Dircandis OK then the label for figure needs to be after `\caption`

Comment: i think i got it now, you define the tab-label not just with "\label" but with the additional command you gave above! (the hyperref link to the figure works, the one to the table doesnt, but i take it as it is :)