# Place threeparttable next to figure

Tags: floats, threeparttable

I would like to place a threeparttable next to a figure and am unable to do so (I couldn't find an example that uses threeparttable). Here is what I was trying (though this doesn't work):

```
\begin{figure}\centering
    \begin{table}[h!] \small
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{\textbf{X on Y} }
    \label{XYZ}
        \begin{tabular}{ p{4.1cm}  o{1.2cm} p{1.2cm}  }
        \hline
            &  (1) & (2)    \\ 
            &  (3) & (4)    \\ 
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
       \begin{tablenotes}
          \footnotesize
         \item \textbf{Note:} XXX \\
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
  \qquad
  \rule{2cm}{3cm}% = graphic
  \caption{Double figure/table combo!}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks for any and all thoughts there.

Comment: Where is the figure in your code? I'm guessing you're after something like the second part of this answer: [Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6854) You can place the whole `threeparttable` in a `minipage`. (By the way, you're missing the closing brace for the `\caption`.)

Comment: How is the `C` column type defined? Should the figure have a caption of its own?

Comment: Apologies, mis-copied the code. Now updated! (Also, changed C to P for columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard method with `\captionof`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,threeparttable,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\captionof{figure}{The figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\small
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\textbf{X on Y}}
\label{XYZ}

\begin{tabular}{ p{4.1cm}  p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm}  }
\hline
A    &  (1) & (2)    \\ 
B    &  (3) & (4)    \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item \textbf{Note:} XXX
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the reverse order:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,threeparttable,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\small
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\textbf{X on Y}}
\label{XYZ}

\begin{tabular}{ p{4.1cm}  p{1.2cm} p{1.2cm}  }
\hline
A    &  (1) & (2)    \\ 
B    &  (3) & (4)    \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item \textbf{Note:} XXX
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\captionof{figure}{The figure}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the `%` that kills the space which would be added by the end-of-line.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. When I try to put the figure to the right of the table (taking out from begin minipage to the end of that command), it goes underneath. Any particular trick to switching these?

Comment: @coding_heart You probably forgot the `%` after the first `\end{minipage}`

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work. I'm removing: `\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\captionof{figure}{The figure}
\end{minipage}`" and putting the `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` but that isn't doing the trick. Note that I am putting this after the first  `\end{minipage}` and it is followed by `\end{table}`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @coding_heart Works for me; see edit.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the clarification there and supporting code.