# Align figure next to table

Tags: tables, floats

I am struggling to align figure next to table. The code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions) and it is:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{figures/strategy_I_no_filter_ROC}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure beside a figure}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}\hline
        Strategy        &  I     &  II   \\\hline
        precision$_0$   & 0.769  &  0.783\\
        precision$_1$   & 0.806  &  0.793\\
        recall$_0$      & 0.804  &  0.796\\  
        recall$_1$      & 0.769  &  0.774\\
        f$_1^{macro}$   & 0.788  &  0.786\\
        AUC             & 0.849  &  0.855\\\hline                 
    \end{tabular}
      \captionof{table}{Classification results of normal intervals versus precursors to depression.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

here is my ugly result:

[image]

- How to align captions? The table caption contains two rows and it goes up.
- How to make the figure the same size as the table? Without chasing every single millimeter of its size.
- How to crop white space around the figure (there is some distance between the caption and figure. I would like to 'zoom-in' the figure, to make it bigger.

**EDIT**

Thanks to great answer, but the figure is squashed. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: In your edit, it looks as if you did not build the `tabular` with bottom alignment.  In that case, `\ht\mytablecontent` will only obtain half of the required value, because the rest will be "depth" instead of "height".

Comment: Indeed, if I take my answer and remove the `[b]` from the `tabular` construction in `\mytable`, I get your edited figure aspect.  So don't forget the `[b]` in your `tabular` construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I address the 3 issues of the OP in the following ways:

1. I use 2 `minipage`s foe each figure/table, with the `\captionof` placed under the content via `\stackunder`, so that the baselines of the two parts agree.  Part of this also is to make `tabular` content with `[b]`ottom alignment (which is the alignment of `\includegraphics`).
2. I save the `tabular` content in advance of the line construction, and use its height to set the height of the included graphic.
3. The `\stackunder` takes an optional argument that sets the gap between the stacked items, in this case the content and the `\captionof`.  Default is 3pt.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\savestack\mytable{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}\hline
        Strategy        &  I     &  II   \\\hline
        precision$_0$   & 0.769  &  0.783\\
        precision$_1$   & 0.806  &  0.793\\
        recall$_0$      & 0.804  &  0.796\\  
        recall$_1$      & 0.769  &  0.774\\
        f$_1^{macro}$   & 0.788  &  0.786\\
        AUC             & 0.849  &  0.855\\\hline                 
    \end{tabular}
}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \stackunder{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=\ht\mytablecontent,
    width=0.6\linewidth]{figures/strategy_I_no_filter_ROC}
      \end{minipage}}
    {\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure beside a figure}
  \end{minipage}}
  \hfill
  \stackunder{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \mytable
    \end{minipage}}
    {\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
      \captionof{table}{Classification results of normal intervals versus precursors to depression.}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks, but surpassingly I get the figure squashed (please see the edited question)

Comment: @ArnoldKlein That is because I set both the height and the width of the `\includegraphic` (just to prove to myself that it centered relative to the caption).  In general, just set the `height=`, and the width will be set to preserve the aspect.

Comment: amazing, I missed out the [b]. Now it works as charm. Thanks!

Comment: @ArnoldKlein You are welcome.  That is one annoying aspect...that `\includegraphics` are bottom-aligned, whereas `tabular` is, by default, center-aligned.  It causes no end of confusion.