# Align baselines of figure and table using minipage and stackunder

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, stackengine, xcoffins

I'm trying to place a figure and a table side by side so that the baselines, rather than the captions, of both are aligned:

The answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370183/align-figure-next-to-table) does this `\stackunder` with minipages, but uses
a table with a bottom caption. I tweaked the code, but I can't seem to get the minipage
`[b]`s and `[t]`s right. I want the bottom of the table to be exactly at the bottom of the image:

[image: 1]

Here's the code that produces the image above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\stackunder{
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
}
{
    \begin{minipage}[]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure with a long caption. A figure with a long caption. A figure with a long caption.}
    \end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\stackunder{
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \captionof{table}{A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption.
    A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. }
    \end{minipage}
}
{
    \begin{minipage}[]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}\hline
        a & b & c\\\hline
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        4 & 5 & 6\\
        7 & 8 & 9\\\hline                 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MWE requires only small changes.  For the tabular, you used `\stackunder{<caption>}{<tabular}` which associates the overall baseline with the `<caption>`.  Instead, use `\stackon{<tabular>}{<caption>}` so that the tabular is associated with the baseline.  Then, to get the proper baseline alignment of the `tabular`, you need to make the surrounding `minipage` bottom-aligned, with the `[b]` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\stackunder{
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}
    \end{minipage}
}
{
    \begin{minipage}[]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \captionof{figure}{A figure with a long caption. A figure with a long caption. A figure with a long caption.}
    \end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\stackon{
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}\hline
        a & b & c\\\hline
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        4 & 5 & 6\\
        7 & 8 & 9\\\hline                 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
}{    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \captionof{table}{A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption.
    A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. }
    \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach based on package `xcoffins`.

It is a package created to facilitate the precise layout of stuff on the page: text, tables, images, graphics, etc., in a very simple but precise way. Zero guessing.

Handy to construct cover and title pages according to specifications.

There are three steps:

**(1)** Fill in the content in 4 special boxes (`\Figurex` ,  `\Tablex`, `\CaptionTablex` and `\CaptionFigurex` ). Please note that exactly your content was used.

You can think of them as minipages with the advantage that they have *many predefined points* to attach to each other.

**(2)** Assemble the boxes together. In this simple case just the left/right-top/bottom corner of a box with the left/right-top/bottom corner of the previous box. (The first box is an empty box `\Framex`).

For example `\JoinCoffins\Framex[\Figurex-r,\Figurex-b]\Tablex[l,b](1em,0pt)` will join  the right-bottom corner of the figure with the left-bottom corner of the table (**as specified**) with a added x-offset of 1em.

**(3)** Typeset the whole set.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576386/161015 for a more extensive explanation.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{xcoffins} % added  <<<<

\NewCoffin\Framex
\NewCoffin\Figurex
\NewCoffin\Tablex
\NewCoffin\CaptionTablex
\NewCoffin\CaptionFigurex

\begin{document}

% Set the content in boxes  
\SetVerticalCoffin\Figurex{0.48\textwidth}{%
\noindent\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}    
}   

\SetVerticalCoffin\Tablex{0.48\textwidth}{%
\centering\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}\hline
    a & b & c\\\hline
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    4 & 5 & 6\\
    7 & 8 & 9\\\hline                 
\end{tabular}
}   

\SetVerticalCoffin\CaptionTablex{0.48\textwidth}{%  
    \captionof{table}{A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption.
    A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. A table with a long caption. }    
}

\SetVerticalCoffin\CaptionFigurex{0.48\textwidth}{%
\captionof{figure}{A figure with a long caption. A figure with a long caption. A figure with a long caption.}
}   

% Join the boxes
\JoinCoffins\Framex[l,t]\Figurex[l,t]
\JoinCoffins\Framex[\Figurex-r,\Figurex-b]\Tablex[l,b](1em,0pt)% x offset = 1em to the right
\JoinCoffins\Framex[\Figurex-l,\Figurex-b]\CaptionFigurex[l,t](0pt, -2ex) %y offset = 2ex down
\JoinCoffins\Framex[\Tablex-l, \Tablex-t]\CaptionTablex[l,b]

% Typeset the assembly
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex

\end{document}
```