# image side by side with table

Tags: tables, diagrams, alignment

Good morning,

I would like to put the picture on the left of the table, all horizontally.

When I try [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6869/179307) it doesn't work. What changes is the picture and table are aligned with left margin aligned vertically, but both captions remained centered.

I can't seem to do it, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

The code is this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{uniformity_machine.PNG}
  \caption{Uniformity machine}
  \label{fig:uniformitymachine}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

{\centering \hfill
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c |c | }
    \hline
    \small
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}  &  \textbf{Unit} \\
    \hline
    Dimension (wxdxh) & 1 725x2 800x2 500 & mm \\
    \hline
    Weight & 3 100 & kg\\
    \hline
    Rim diameter & 13 - 25 & in\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Electrical requirements} & 3 & Phase\\
    & 400 & V \\
    & 50 & Hz \\
    & 35 & A \\
    \hline
    Pneumatic requirements & 600 & kPa\\
    \hline
    Cycle time & 20 & s\\
     \hline
    Cost & NUMBER & EUR \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Uniformity machine specifications}\label{tab2}
\end{table}
\hfill}
```

Comment: You can use `minipage` for this. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can take a look at the `floatrow` package.

Comment: I tried both alternatives but none of them worked... what do I do now?

Comment: I voted to leave this question closed, because in the mean time it was reasked (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469837/image-side-by-side-with-table-keeps-on-not-working) and got an answer there.