# Image side by side with table keeps on not working

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment

Good morning,

I would like to put the picture on the left of the table, all horizontally.

When I try [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions) it doesn't work. What changes is the picture and table are aligned with left margin aligned vertically, with both captions remaining centered.

I can't seem to do it at all, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

The code is this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.50]{uniformity_machine.PNG}
  \caption{Uniformity machine}
  \label{fig:uniformitymachine}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

{\centering \hfill
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c |c | }
    \hline
    \small
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}  &  \textbf{Unit} \\
    \hline
    Dimension (wxdxh) & 1 725x2 800x2 500 & mm \\
    \hline
    Weight & 3 100 & kg\\
    \hline
    Rim diameter & 13 - 25 & in\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Electrical requirements} & 3 & Phase\\
    & 400 & V \\
    & 50 & Hz \\
    & 35 & A \\
    \hline
    Pneumatic requirements & 600 & kPa\\
    \hline
    Cycle time & 20 & s\\
     \hline
    Cost & NUMBER & EUR \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Uniformity machine specifications}\label{tab2}
\end{table}
\hfill}
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which of the seven answers given in the link you provided did you try to implement?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that your table and image will fit besides each other unless you either reduce the margin size or restructure the table layout.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \captionof{figure}{Uniformity machine}
  \label{fig:uniformitymachine}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
   \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | }
    \hline
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}  &  \textbf{Unit} \\
    \hline
    Dimension (wxdxh) & 1 725x2 800x2 500 & mm \\
    \hline
    Weight & 3 100 & kg\\
    \hline
    Rim diameter & 13 - 25 & in\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Electrical requirements} & 3 & Phase\\
    & 400 & V \\
    & 50 & Hz \\
    & 35 & A \\
    \hline
    Pneumatic requirements & 600 & kPa\\
    \hline
    Cycle time & 20 & s\\
     \hline
    Cost & NUMBER & EUR \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Uniformity machine specifications}
    \label{tab2}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Maria Good to hear that it worked! If you have some time, please have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html

Comment: @Maria If samcarter's answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the tick in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `floatrow` environment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption, floatrow, multirow, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\CenterFloatBoxes
\floatsetup{floatrowsep = qquad}
\begin{floatrow}[2]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption*{Konrad Klapheck: \emph{Les Liaisons Dangereuses} (1968)}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{klapheck1}}
\killfloatstyle
\ttabbox{ \begin{tabular}{| c | c |c | }
    \hline
    \small
    \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Unit} \\
    \hline
    Dimension (wxdxh) & 1 725x2 800x2 500 & mm \\
    \hline
    Weight & 3 100 & kg\\
    \hline
    Rim diameter & 13 - 25 & in\\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Electrical requirements} & 3 & Phase\\
    & 400 & V \\
    & 50 & Hz \\
    & 35 & A \\
    \hline
    Pneumatic requirements & 600 & kPa\\
    \hline
    Cycle time & 20 & s\\
     \hline
    Cost & NUMBER & EUR \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}{ \caption{Uniformity machine specifications}\label{tab2}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]