# Figure and Table not aligned

Tags: tables, floats, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a table and a figure in  Latex, but I`m not getting the results I want. I followed this answer : [Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions)

This is the code I used

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{pgf}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \centering
    \rule{6.4cm}{3.6cm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
      Table head & Table head \\ \hline
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But this is what I get : 
[image]

Comment: you want `[t]` aligned minipages not `[b]` so they both align on the `vspace{0pt}` (which otherwise is doing nothing)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Try replacing `[b]`with `[t]`.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard  , it works

Comment: It should also be noted that [t] and [b] select the baseline of the first and last lines in a minipage or tabular.  Hence the \vspace in Mico's solution aligns with the \hline in the tabular.  \raisebox has more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code features several unneeded `minipage` environments. Remove the "wrappers", and use the `[t]` positioning specifier for both the remaining `minipage` environment and the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{6.4cm}
    \vspace{0sp}
    \rule{\textwidth}{3.6cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cc@{}} 
        \hline
        Table head & Table head   \\ 
        \hline
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\
        Some values & Some values \\ 
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```