# Table and plot next to each other

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying to put side-by-side a plot and a table. I have tried using minipage and tried applying the following solution to my problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions). I cannot seem to get it working correctly.

The file is called conMat_NN.pdf

File location: https://easyupload.io/lethp7

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, angle=0]{plots/conMat_NN.pdf}
\caption{Neural Network: Confusion Matrix}
\label{fig:conMat_NN}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
Statistics \\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Year 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Neural Network} \\
\hline
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{some caption}
\label{tab:stats}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

EDIT:

With current version: The table overlays the figure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}%
}{%
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, angle=0]{plots/conMat_NN.pdf}
\caption{Neural Network: Confusion Matrix}
\label{fig:conMat_NN}
\end{center}
}
\capbtabbox{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Year 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Neural Network} \\
\hline
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which of the answers from the [question you linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions) are you trying to use here? Please provide a link to the specific answer (look for *share* at the end of the answer, right-click  on it and select *Copy Link Location*, or something approaching).

Comment: This one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6869/173150 , however I am open to any general working solution - Thanks for highlighting the "share" option I never saw / realised to use it before.

Comment: Okay, but the code you posted doesn't contain any occurrence of `floatrow`, therefore you don't show us that you tried to apply that answer. Please show us what you tried, then we can help you further.

Comment: I added my version in which the table overlays the plot. I was hoping for a long table to the right of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to apply the solution in the [answer you linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6869/173150), you need to replace the `\rule` (which produces the big black rectangle) with your image: `\includegraphics[...]{...}`. Using `example-image` that is present in all TeX distributions, we obtain:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
}{%
  \caption{Neural Network: Confusion Matrix}%
  \label{fig:conMat_NN}%
}%
\capbtabbox{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Year & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Neural Network} \\
\hline
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}`, so the image uses all the available horizontal space (approx. half of `\textwidth`). Use `0.7\linewidth` or so for something a bit narrower.

I also fixed your table “header” (Year 1, etc.). One `&` was presumably missing between `Year` and `1`. Moreover, without all `&`s, the right vertical rule would not be drawn.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help, it works great and looks very nice in the paper.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the `floatrow` package, which can manage mixed float types with `\killfloatstyle` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]\TopFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Neural Network: Confusion Matrix}\label{fig:conMat_NN}}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, angle=0]{conMat_NN.pdf}}
\killfloatstyle
\ttabbox{\caption{some caption}\label{tab:stats}}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Statistics} \\
\hline
Year 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Neural Network} \\
\hline
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
Accuracy & 0.78 & 0.76 & 0.74 & 0.72 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]