# How can I set the caption to the top of table?

Tags: tables

I created a illustration where I have a image on the left side and a table on the right side.

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    ruledheaders=section,%Ebene bis zu der die Überschriften mit Linien abgetrennt werden, vgl. DEMO-TUDaPub
    class=report,% Basisdokumentenklasse. Wählt die Korrespondierende KOMA-Script Klasse
    thesis={type=master,department = matgeo},% Dokumententyp Thesis, für Dissertationen siehe die Demo-Datei DEMO-TUDaPhd
    accentcolor=8b,% Auswahl der Akzentfarbe
    custommargins=false,% Ränder werden mithilfe von typearea automatisch berechnet
    marginpar=false,% Kopfzeile und Fußzeile erstrecken sich nicht über die Randnotizspalte
    %BCOR=5mm,%Bindekorrektur, falls notwendig
    parskip=half-,%Absatzkennzeichnung durch Abstand vgl. KOMA-Script
    fontsize=12pt,%Basisschriftgröße laut Corporate Design ist mit 9pt häufig zu klein
    %logofile=example-image, %Falls die Logo Dateien nicht vorliegen
    pdfa=true,
]{tudapub}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{array}

\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Microreactor.PNG}}{
\caption{Sketch of MIMiX full system. A combination of microreactor and control system.}
\label{fig: Mikroreaktor}
}
\capbtabbox{
    \centering
    %\captionsetup{width=.75\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{R{5cm} C{3cm} }
    \cmidrule[1pt]{1-2}
    \textbf{Properties}&\textbf{Limits}\\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    \textbf{Pressure [hPa] }                &       180 -  1000\\
    \textbf{Temperatur [\text{°}C]}         &       250 - 293\\
    \textbf{RH [\%]}                        &       dry - >93\\
    \textbf{Accurency <80\% RH [\%]}        &       3\\
    \textbf{Accurency >80\% RH [\%]}        &       5\\
    \cmidrule[1pt]{1-2}
    \end{tabular*}
    \label{tab: ReaktorEigenschaften}
}{\caption[Important Limits and parameters of the MIMiX system.]{Important Limits and parameters of \\the MIMiX system.}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How can I set the caption of the table on the top?

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
```

is not working? Does someone have any idea?

Comment: Please make sure your example is complete, such that others can copy and test the example as is. Here there is no document class.

Comment: Done! Sorry I am new to LaTex. I used the package "tuda-ci". It is a package specifically for the corporate design of the institute.

Comment: Why you use `floatrow` environment for including images? Does you document class not support more simple `\begin{figure}\caption{caption now will be on the top of float}\label:fig:<label name>}\includegraphics[<options, if exist>]{<image file name>}\end{figure}`?

Comment: Because I am trying to place the image and the table side by side. I found this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6850/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-independent-captions and implemented it in my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can use the `subcaption` package instead. If you can use this package, the solution is pretty straightforward. For a caption on top of the table, put it on the top and for in the bottom of the table, put in the bottom. For your case, the code is

```
\documentclass[
    english,
    ruledheaders=section,%Ebene bis zu der die Überschriften mit Linien abgetrennt werden, vgl. DEMO-TUDaPub
    class=report,% Basisdokumentenklasse. Wählt die Korrespondierende KOMA-Script Klasse
    thesis={type=master,department = matgeo},% Dokumententyp Thesis, für Dissertationen siehe die Demo-Datei DEMO-TUDaPhd
    accentcolor=8b,% Auswahl der Akzentfarbe
    custommargins=false,% Ränder werden mithilfe von typearea automatisch berechnet
    marginpar=false,% Kopfzeile und Fußzeile erstrecken sich nicht über die Randnotizspalte
    %BCOR=5mm,%Bindekorrektur, falls notwendig
    parskip=half-,%Absatzkennzeichnung durch Abstand vgl. KOMA-Script
    fontsize=12pt,%Basisschriftgröße laut Corporate Design ist mit 9pt häufig zu klein
    %logofile=example-image, %Falls die Logo Dateien nicht vorliegen
    pdfa=true,
]{tudapub}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[B]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Microreactor.png} % added the first result from a search on google for microreactor as the image
\caption{Sketch of MIMiX full system. A combination of microreactor and control system.}
\label{fig: Mikroreaktor}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subtable}[B]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption[Important Limits and parameters of the MIMiX system.]{Important Limits and parameters of \\the MIMiX system.}
    \label{tab: ReaktorEigenschaften}
    \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{R{5cm} C{3cm} }
    \cmidrule[1pt]{1-2}
    \textbf{Properties}&\textbf{Limits}\\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    \textbf{Pressure [hPa] }                &       180 -  1000\\
    \textbf{Temperatur [C]}         &       250 - 293\\
    \textbf{RH [\%]}                        &       dry - >93\\
    \textbf{Accurency <80\% RH [\%]}        &       3\\
    \textbf{Accurency >80\% RH [\%]}        &       5\\
    \cmidrule[1pt]{1-2}
    \end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]