# (Vertical) Alignment of caption when placing two tables beside each other

Tags: captions, minipage, subcaption, alignment

I followed the approach outlined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6854) to place two tables (and also figures and tables) beside each other.
Unfortunately if the height of one of the two floats is greater than the other one the captions are no longer aligned.

Image and MWE of this problem below:
[image]
MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \label{tab:state0_eval_sarsa}
        \caption{Bewertung State 0 \\ bester Sarsa Agent}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \toprule
        Aktion  & Bewertung \\ \midrule
        0   & -0,0283 \\
        1   & -0,0258 \\
        2   & -0,0223 \\
        3   & -0,0272 \\
        4   & 0,0019  \\
        5   & -0,0218 \\
        6   & -0,0337 \\
        7   & -0,0394 \\
        8   & -0,0274 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \caption{Bewertung Aktionsklassen State 0 bester Sarsa Agent}
        \label{tab:state0_eval_sarsa_aggregated}
        \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \toprule
        Aktion  & Bewertung \\ \midrule
        Ecke    & -0,0279 \\
        Kante   & -0,0286 \\
        Mitte   &  0,0019 \\ \bottomrule
        
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}` The optional argument `t` puts the contents at the top of the box.

[image: d]

The `\hfill` between the minipages pushes the tables to the left and right edge of the text area.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% to add dummy text

\begin{document}
    
    \kant[1]
    
    \noindent\begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \label{tab:state0_eval_sarsa}
            \caption{Bewertung State 0 \\ bester Sarsa Agent}
            \begin{tabular}{lc}
                \toprule
                Aktion  & Bewertung \\ \midrule
                0   & -0,0283 \\
                1   & -0,0258 \\
                2   & -0,0223 \\
                3   & -0,0272 \\
                4   & 0,0019  \\
                5   & -0,0218 \\
                6   & -0,0337 \\
                7   & -0,0394 \\
                8   & -0,0274 \\ \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}\hfill%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Bewertung Aktionsklassen State 0 bester Sarsa Agent}
            \label{tab:state0_eval_sarsa_aggregated}
            \begin{tabular}{lc}
                \toprule
                Aktion  & Bewertung \\ \midrule
                Ecke    & -0,0279 \\
                Kante   & -0,0286 \\
                Mitte   &  0,0019 \\ \bottomrule                
            \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}

\kant[1]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with the `floatrow` package. I also loaded `siunitx` to have a better formatting of the numbers in the right column.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\sisetup{table-format=-1.4} %\captionsetup{format=plain}
\begin{floatrow}
 \ttabbox[1.4\FBwidth]{\caption{Bewertung State 0 \\ bester Sarsa Agent}\label{tab:state0_eval_sarsa}}
 {\begin{tabular}{lS}
 \toprule
 Aktion & {Bewertung} \\ \midrule
 0 & -0,0283 \\
 1 & -0,0258 \\
 2 & -0,0223 \\
 3 & -0,0272 \\
 4 & 0,0019 \\
 5 & -0,0218 \\
 6 & -0,0337 \\
 7 & -0,0394 \\
 8 & -0,0274 \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}}
 \captionsetup{format=plain}
 \ttabbox[1.5\FBwidth]{\caption{Bewertung Aktionsklassen State 0 bester Sarsa Agent} \label{tab:state0_eval_sarsa_aggregated}}
 {\begin{tabular}{lS}
 \toprule
 Aktion &{ Bewertung} \\ \midrule
 Ecke & -0,0279 \\
 Kante & -0,0286 \\
 Mitte & 0,0019 \\ \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution and also for the inclusion of `siunitx` package. I will look into it and use it in the future.
I decided to accept Simon's answer as it solved the problem without using another package.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom align of two tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
    
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[]{%
            \begin{tabular}[b]{c|cc}
                a & b & c\\
                \hline
                1 & 2 & 3\\
                x & y &z\\
                \hline
        \end{tabular}}\qquad
        \subfloat[]{%
            \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
                
                1 & 2\\
                \hline
                x & y\\
                a & b\\
                A & B\\
                \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]